Issues with laravel_flutter_pusher_plus on Flutter 3.24.4 and Gradle 8.3
I hope you are doing well.
I'm using this package locally in my application: https://pub.dev/packages/laravel_flutter_pusher_plus. I placed the package folder inside the main application folder and imported it in pubspec.yaml like this:
laravel_flutter_pusher:
    path: packages/laravel_flutter_pusher_plus

Here is the content of the old build.gradle file for the package.
group 'dev.micazi.laravel_flutter_pusher_plus'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:2.0.2'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.4'
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
}

After upgrading Flutter to:
Flutter 3.24.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 603104015d (2 weeks ago) • 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
Engine • revision db49896cf2
Tools • Dart 3.5.4 • DevTools 2.37.3

I am no longer able to build the application. I am using Gradle 8.3 and Java version 19.
Can you help me modify build.gradle package file to work with the current Flutter version, along with Gradle 8.3, Java 19, and Kotlin 1.8.22?
Thank you
